# How do I generate a list of items based on selected dropdown item?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, razor, drop-down-menu, viewbag

I would like to filter a list of items based on the dropdown option the user has selected.

This is my dropdown:

```
<select class="form-control" onchange="loadFilteredList()" id="conditionSelect">
      <option disabled value="" selected="selected">Please select a filter</option>
      <option>Under 18</option>
      <option>Above 18</option>
</select>
```

This is the loop I am using to generate the list with:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="ageOverview">
    <tr>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
        <th>Col3</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var person in ViewBag.persons)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@person.FirstName</td>
            <td>@person.MiddleName</td>
            <td>@pperson.LastName</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I want to load the correct list each time the user selects an option from the dropdown.

The ViewBag with the data is filled within the controller I have. At the moment there is a ViewBag for the first option from the dropdopdown, and a ViewBag for the second option from the dropdown. Don't know if this is the right approach but I'm very new to this and would like to get some advice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Kinda depends on how many items are in there. If there's not a lot of choices, just pop it into a client side place like a script var or hidden input and use that to filter on the client. If there's a lot of options, and it would pollute your DOM and hurt load times, make a async call to a controller to do it.

Comment: Remember, the view bag is server side. You can't react to a dropdownselect event and do anything with it as far as MVC goes. You'd need a new post request, ajax, or some other way to get new values from the server (postback for web forms).

Comment: There are going to be a lot of items in there. Probably over 1000.. I have the data in my controller as well. How do I get it within my view as efficient as possible? Any code snippets?

Comment: Well, the viewbag is only alive for one request. So, it's not really a place you'd store things like this because you'd just need to regenerate it on each request, and that sort of thing usually comes from a DB or other expensive place. Also, I'm not sure if Vue.js would look like what I'm used to (mvc + jquery). I'll give you some basic architecture ideas as an answer so we don't kill the comments here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without accounting for the Vue tag you have here, my typical way to manage something with large (more than a couple hundred DOM elements, and you mentioned 1000+) is to hook it with small controller actions to avoid polluting the DOM, which slows things down a lot.

We have to look at options, though, because you're going to take a hit somewhere. You have to decide where. Large number of DOM elements vs bandwidth of requests. Storing the data in Session so it's available for multiple post requests or requerying whatever generated it.

So for purposes here, I'll assume we do not want to have tons of items in the DOM and just show/hide, which is the simplest way, but not good as you start adding items and combinations or mobile users try to load a page, etc. I'm also colored by the name of your function, loadFilteredList, which to me just yells out "add another filter" requirement from someone soon.

**So here's the basic design:**

A controller method returns the table content you have here as a partial view.

It (the controller method) optionally has an argument that is the filter option. (more of those can be added later; the point is, the controller is doing the filtering and sending data)

Your javascript then for the onchange is just firing off a post request to the controller for new filtered data. You can use jquery or vanilla to set the html content as needed. Your controller either gets fresh data for filtering or uses session. Whatever is best for your needs here. You don't need ViewBag though, it's not for this type of situation.

The downside of this type of design is that a fresh request is sent in the background to the server for each filter. The upside is that hopefully your payloads are small enough, so it's not as expensive to do it that way as to return every possible row so that it can be filtered client side.

Comment: Hmm there are some good things in here to consider. I have methods in my controller that get the right filter data for each one individually. I'm not sure how I can set it up as efficient as possible tho.. Do you have any code snippets or something I can dive into?